# How to get the live tasktracker node on JT by cmd line

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to find the no of live Tasktracker node , which are available on JT url, but by command line, actually I dont have access to JT and NN URL.

regards
Vikas Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop comes with [hadoop job](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#job) command.try that.

it will list all the subcommands available in it if you type `hadoop job`.

`list-active-trackers` option may be useful for you

Comment: The `list-active-trackers` is no where in the referred url.

Comment: may be documentation did not list that option or am referring to different version.